# Need help identifying this component

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify this part (on left) which I found while cleaning my room. I have placed a micro SD card next to it to give an idea of its size.

[image: part next to microSD]

**Update:** This is what the rear looks like:
[image]

Comment: Looks like an LED, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: It's an NSA mind control... I'VE SAID TOO MUCH!

Comment: Almost certainly an LED as Anindo says. BUT why is the photos not sharp so we can see it MUCH more clearly. Use more light. If necessary move further away into focus range. If necessary brace camera / phone on something solid. Almost any camera or phone-camera will do much better than this. Having enough light often makes an immense difference.

Answer (score 15):

The component is a PLCC (Plastic Leadless Chip Carrier) type LED.

The one in the question seems to be a single color LED. A similar one, but RGB type:

[image: LED]

([source](http://store.aztronics.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=195))